# Sublime text errors. (import?)

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, sublimetext3

Tried to run this code in Sublime:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar10
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
import pickle

pickle_in = open("X.pickle","rb")
X = pickle.load(pickle_in)

pickle_in = open("y.pickle","rb")
y = pickle.load(pickle_in)

X = X/255.0

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), input_shape=X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())  # this converts our 3D feature maps to 1D feature vectors

model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X, y, batch_size=32, epochs=10, validation_split=0.3)
```

but I keep getting those errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\catsdogsai\catsdogsai\catsdogsai.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\Edward\Anaconda3\envs\aitest\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\Edward\Anaconda3\envs\aitest\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\Edward\Anaconda3\envs\aitest\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\Users\Edward\Anaconda3\envs\aitest\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 34, in <module>
    from . import _mklinit
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have installed all the modules, activated the env on Sublime too but still nothing.

Triend reinstalling everything but it's still nothing good, same errors.

Comment: "The specified module could not be found."  Looks like one of your modules is not installed, according to the traceback.  `tensorflow` maybe

Comment: Maybe add the code you have written, or at least the modules you imported.

Comment: @Alex_P added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

I had to downgrade the CUDA from 10.1 to 10.0 since apparently tensorflow only supports 10.0.